# Missing coupon field in cart/checkout process

Tags: cart, checkout, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have added coupon code for free shipping in the Shopping Cart Price Rules (Magento 1.4.1.1), but I don't see any coupon code field in a cart or checkout process.

I have checked `checkout.xml` file and proper line exists

```
<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
```

Edit:

It looks like coupon functionality was removed from `coupon.phtml` file, which contains now only

```
<!-- coupon code removed-->
```

Can someone could to provide proper file for that Magento version?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download Magento 1.4.1.1 from [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download) then click on **Release Archives** tab and find the release version that you're looking for and download it, then extract it, then copy `coupon.phtml` from base theme `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/coupon.phtml` to your active theme folder.

Or just copy the following code:

```
<form id="discount-coupon-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/couponPost') ?>" method="post">
    <div class="discount">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('Discount Codes') ?></h2>
        <div class="discount-form">
            <label for="coupon_code"><?php echo $this->__('Enter your coupon code if you have one.') ?></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="remove" id="remove-coupone" value="0" />
            <div class="input-box">
                <input class="input-text" id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCouponCode()) ?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="buttons-set">
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Apply Coupon') ?>" class="button" onclick="discountForm.submit(false)" value="<?php echo $this->__('Apply Coupon') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Apply Coupon') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php if(strlen($this->getCouponCode())): ?>
                    &nbsp; <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Cancel Coupon') ?>" class="button" onclick="discountForm.submit(true)" value="<?php echo $this->__('Cancel Coupon') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Cancel Coupon') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var discountForm = new VarienForm('discount-coupon-form');
discountForm.submit = function (isRemove) {
    if (isRemove) {
        $('coupon_code').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('remove-coupone').value = "1";
    } else {
        $('coupon_code').addClassName('required-entry');
        $('remove-coupone').value = "0";
    }
    return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(discountForm)();
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Added that code to the coupon.phtml file, refreshed layouts, cleared cache and still no coupon code field.

Comment: Well, it looks like that `cart.phtml` doesn't have coupon functionality as well :\

Comment: Just a note - I'm using one page checkout layout.

Comment: @JackTheKnife are you still having problem with coupon form?

Comment: Yes - coupon cannot be applied. Even I have try to add fixed discount but it doesn't work at all. More here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19155/free-shipping-coupon-is-not-applying