# Free shipping coupon is not applying

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, coupon-codes

I have created a coupon code for free shipping following steps similar to described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17806/free-shipping-if-subtotal-greater-than-or-equal-50), but when I try to use valid or not valid coupon code Magento (1.4.1.1) does nothing.

Site [URL](http://www.nestcasa.com/accessories/scent/baobab-collection.html/) and coupon code is TEST

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: can you add this code if its not there `<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>` to `template/checkout/cart.phtml` this should allow to read success and error messages

Comment: @Aboodred1 Added as `Error messages:` under the grey table. For me it looks like form `/checkout/cart/updatePost/` is not executed at all

Comment: your coupon form is missing the form tag

Comment: I have copied all from another topic about `coupon.html` file missing content, which contains `<form id="discount-coupon-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/couponPost') ?>" method="post">`

Comment: Maybe I need to move it out of the cart items form loop?

Comment: and that what the problem - form got rendered within another form loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to remove coupon code form from **cart table** footer and add it above **Totals table**.

Edit `cart.phtml` file under your theme template `app/design/frontend/custom_package/custom_theme/template/checkout/cart.phtml` and add the following code within this div `<div class="cartRow">` before `<div class="cartRight">`:

```
<div class="cartRight" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
</div>
```

The output should look like this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My dig

```
app/design/frontend/custom_package/custom_theme/template/checkout/cart.phtml
```

and add the following code within this div `<div class="cartRow">`

before `<div class="cartRight">`:

```
<div class="cartRight" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
</div>
```